# Open files under webroot without downloading them

Tags: php, apache, localhost

When i go to my localhost from browser, I see a list of files stored there which are xls or word.
When i open word/xls or other such kind of files, they dont open, but i get an option in firefox whether to open them or save them, if i open them, they get downloaded first and then that copy of downloaded file gets open.
I want a way to open the files without them getting downloaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's browser configuration. You cannot influence this behaviour, because it is not desireable from a security standpoint to let websites make the call which application to use or how to open files.

Each file you download via a website is associated with a *media type* or [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_types). Word files for example use `application/msword`.

And that's about all the webserver says about a file. There is an additional HTTP header `Content-Disposition:` which can alternate between `inline` (default) and `attachment` (forces downloads). But this is unlikely to be set in default webserver setups. You could check this with Firebug (http headers).

But from your description the open dialog is caused by the default Firefox settings. Users have the choice to have some file types opened automatically (there's a checkbox in that dialog IIRC). Websites have no influence over this. PDFs for example are special cases, where the Adobe browser plugin opens it internally in the browser window. (A similar plugin exists for Word files in Internet Explorer, but not for Firefox.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need a system call to do that then. At least on Mac OS X you could theoretically execute an "open /path/to/filename.ext" through a server-side scripting language to cause them to be opened by the default application on the mac. Past that I'm not entirely sure what options you would have.

Comment: pdf and text files do open in browser....... but word/xls and some other types wont open.......